# Kafka, Confluent client, Offset

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, offset, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I have some questions about working with offset in Confluent Kafka client API for .NET. Unfortunately, answers are not obvious and documentation doesn't help me.
How to detect the offset doesn't exists (was deleted, maybe, according to retention rules)?
How to detect the offset points to a deleted message (according to retention rules)?
How to find the first existing message and set the offset to it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set [`auto.offset.reset`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs):

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current
>   offset does not exist any more on the server (**e.g. because that data
>   has been deleted**):
>
> **earliest:** automatically reset the offset to the
>   earliest offset
>
> **latest:** automatically reset the offset to the latest
>   offset
>
> **none:** throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is
>   found for the consumer's group
>
> **anything else:** throw exception to the
>   consumer.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Confluent.Kafka;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var conf = new ConsumerConfig
        { 
            GroupId = "test-consumer-group",
            BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
            // Set auto.offset.reset to `earliest`
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
        };

        using (var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf).Build())
        {
            c.Subscribe("my-topic");

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) => {
                e.Cancel = true; // prevent the process from terminating.
                cts.Cancel();
            };

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
                    }
                    catch (ConsumeException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Ensure the consumer leaves the group cleanly and final offsets are committed.
                c.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this answers the last question, but not how to "detect" the group would be reset